# Which Facebook Graph API version Parse is using?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, facebook-login

I'm using Parse to login users with Facebook (on ios, using the Facebook and Parse ios SDKs).
I always assumed that the Facebook SDK was using the latest version of the API by default, meaning that Parse would probably do the same.

However, if I check the Facebook tokens stored by Parse in the authData field using the Facebook Access Token Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken), it seems that my tokens are generated by a call to API v1.0.

In the `User ID` field, it says 'User last installed this app via API v1.0'.
Also, the `Scopes` field contains permissions that I didn't request (like basic_info, user_location, user_friends)

Anyone knows why ? Is this normal ? Any chances that my app will break on april 30 ?

Thanks !

**Update** : This actually seems to be random. Some tokens have the `User ID` field that says 'User last installed this app via API v1.0', and some others have 'User last installed this app via API v2.x'. And they are all users who signed up today, with the latest version of my app !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Parse with Facebook login for iOS and Android won't require any changes, and your app won't break on 4/30.  We're upgrading our side of things and will be using v2.3 shortly.

Comment: Thanks. If you say the app won't break, that's the most important. But it doesn't explain why the SDK seems to be making calls to the version 1.0 of the API. Also I have received an email from Parse saying that my app was still making calls to the version 1.0 of the API.

Comment: We're still using 1.0 on the server side.  We'll be upgrading shortly, and we should not have sent that email... It was worded poorly and caused some alarm.

Comment: Ok, sorry for being alarming. Being part of Facebook, I guess I should trust that you will migrate everything correctly.

Comment: No worries... yep, we'll take care of it. :)